# Data wont insert and display on my app | Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My app isn't displaying the data i'm inserting into the interface, i'm creating a fighter database where my coach can add fighters from the gym into it. I'm using a card view and recycling adaptor to display all the data but when I click submit it wont display.

Error log:[image: ERROR LOG]

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ArrayList<Item>list = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private ItemAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AlertDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);


        fetchRecords();

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View mView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add,null);

                final EditText input_name = (EditText) mView1.findViewById(R.id.Name);
                final EditText input_age = (EditText) mView1.findViewById(R.id.Age);
                final EditText input_weight = (EditText) mView1.findViewById(R.id.Weight);
                final EditText input_height = (EditText) mView1.findViewById(R.id.Height);
                final EditText input_reach = (EditText) mView1.findViewById(R.id.Reach);
                final Button btnSave = (Button) mView1.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setView(mView1).setTitle("Add new Record")
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        String name = input_name.getText().toString();
                        String age = input_age.getText().toString();
                        String weight = input_weight.getText().toString();
                        String height = input_height.getText().toString();
                        String reach = input_reach.getText().toString();

                        if (name.equals("") && age.equals("") && weight.equals("") && height.equals("")&& reach.equals("")){
                            Snackbar.make(view,"Field incomplete",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else {
                            Save(name,age,name,height,reach);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Snackbar.make(view,"Saving",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();


            }
        });
    }

    public void fetchRecords() {

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(this,list);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.clear();

        Functions functions = new Functions(MainActivity.this);

        ArrayList<Item>data = functions.getAllRecords();

        if (data.size()>0){
            for (int i = 0; i<data.size(); i++){

                int id = data.get(i).getId();
                String namel = data.get(i).getName();
                String agel = data.get(i).getAge();
                String weightl = data.get(i).getWeight();
                String heightl = data.get(i).getHeight();
                String reachl = data.get(i).getReach();

                Item item = new Item();

                item.setId(id);
                item.setName(namel);
                item.setAge(agel);
                item.setWeight(weightl);
                item.setHeight(heightl);
                item.setReach(reachl);
                list.add(item);

            }adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Records found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void Save(String name, String age, String weight, String height, String reach) {


        Functions functions = new Functions(MainActivity.this);
        Item item = new Item();

        item.setName(name);
        item.setAge(age);
        item.setWeight(weight);
        item.setHeight(height);
        item.setReach(reach);
        functions.Insert(item);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fetchRecords();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

---

```
public class Functions extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "crud.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private Fighter fighter = new Fighter();

    public Functions(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(fighter.CREATE_TABLE_PERSON);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + fighter.TABLE_FIGHTER);
    }


    public void Insert(Item item){

        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(fighter.ID,item.getId());
        contentValues.put(fighter.NAME,item.getName());
        contentValues.put(fighter.AGE,item.getAge());
        contentValues.put(fighter.WEIGHT,item.getWeight());
        contentValues.put(fighter.HEIGHT,item.getHeight());
        contentValues.put(fighter.REACH,item.getReach());

        database.insert(fighter.TABLE_FIGHTER,null,contentValues);
    }


    public ArrayList<Item>getAllRecords(){

        ArrayList<Item>list = new ArrayList<Item>();
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + fighter.TABLE_FIGHTER;

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql,null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                item.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                item.setAge(cursor.getString(2));
                item.setWeight(cursor.getString(3));
                item.setHeight(cursor.getString(4));
                item.setReach(cursor.getString(5));


                list.add(item);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        return list;
    }


    public Item getSingleItem(int id){

        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + fighter.TABLE_FIGHTER + " WHERE " + fighter.ID + "=?";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql,new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToNext();

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        item.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        item.setAge(cursor.getString(2));
        item.setWeight(cursor.getString(3));
        item.setHeight(cursor.getString(4));
        item.setReach(cursor.getString(4));

        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        return item;
    }

    public void DeleteItem(int id){

        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(fighter.TABLE_FIGHTER,fighter.ID + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        database.close();
    }

    public void Update(Item item){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(fighter.NAME,item.getName());
        contentValues.put(fighter.AGE,item.getAge());
        contentValues.put(fighter.WEIGHT,item.getWeight());
        contentValues.put(fighter.HEIGHT,item.getHeight());
        contentValues.put(fighter.REACH,item.getReach());
        database.update(fighter.TABLE_FIGHTER,contentValues,fighter.ID + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(item.getId())});

    }


}
```

---

```
public class Fighter {


    public static final String TABLE_FIGHTER = "fighter";



    public static final String ID = "ID";
    public static final String NAME = "Name";
    public static final String AGE = "Age";
    public static final String WEIGHT = "Weight";
    public static final String HEIGHT = "Height";
    public static final String REACH = "Reach";


    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_PERSON = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FIGHTER + "("
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + NAME + " TEXT,"
            + AGE + " TEXT,"
            + WEIGHT + " TEXT,"
            + HEIGHT + " TEXT"
            + REACH + " TEXT"+ ")";

}
```

Comment: Show CREATE_TABLE_PERSON.

Comment: can you show the create table fighter?

Comment: It says reach isnt there but it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, you have missed a comma after   `+ HEIGHT + " TEXT"` .  therefore table is not created properly due to SQL syntax errors.  please try with following. i have added the comma for you.

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_PERSON = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FIGHTER + "("
        + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + NAME + " TEXT,"
        + AGE + " TEXT,"
        + WEIGHT + " TEXT,"
        + HEIGHT + " TEXT,"
        + REACH + " TEXT"+ ")";
```

Comment: This has worked thank you! It still wont let me add more then one entry for some reason? Only shows the first entry.

Comment: does it give you some error when you try to insert the second record? or it just keep inserting records and display you only the first record?

Comment: i think thins might be the reason for the issue. look at your CREATE TABLE statement.          + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"  . According to this primary key should be manually assigned  by the user.  if you look at your code, you are not assigning the primary key values for the Item.  therefore first entry will be created with some default value. it will not allow to create the second entry with the default value as the firdt enrtry has that value for the primary key. assign primary key manually or change it as AUTO_INCREMET Column.

Comment: Amazing help cant thank you enough! It seems to work fine but the update  dosen't seem to work and when I hit delete all of the tables delete....

Comment: what are you trying to update after removing all entries? can you post the code for update and delete here?

Comment: They are located in the functions class at the bottom, thanks